# How can I do a number condition of equal, greater than and less than in Angular using ngSwitch?

Tags: angular

I am learning angular structural directives and I have encountered the following problem, I tried to use the switchcase but I am having a value that is not correct based on my condition.

I want to have an output of average if the grade is lower than 80 or higher than 75 but the output that I am getting is Invalid. However, once I removed the `div` tag of invalid then I do not have an output.

Here is my switch condition.

Template:

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="grade">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="grade >= 75 && grade <= 80">Average</div>
    <div *ngSwitchDefault>Invalid</div>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```js
public grade = 75;
```

Comment: You are using switchCase wrong, you have to provide a value not a condition in the case.

Comment: @B45i can you provide a solution like a code please? to help me visualize what I need to do, as I am still in the progress of learning this framework.

Answer (score 1):

`ngSwitchCase` cannot hold a condition but value only as it does simple `===` evaluation. But what you can do is to create some kind of state for your grades in the component which you will then provide to `ngSwitchCase`. For instance in component (I suggest creating a separate file for Grade object) :

```
class Grade {
  value: number;
  state: string
}

var marks: Grade = new Grade();
marks.value = 7;
 
switch (true) {
    case (marks.value >= 0 && marks.value <= 4):
        marks.state = "bad"
        break;
    case (marks.value >= 5 && marks.value <= 8):
        marks.state = "better"
        break;
    default:
        marks.state = "invalid"
}
```

Than in your HTML:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="grade.state">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="bad">Bad</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="better">Average</div>
  <div *ngSwitchDefault>Invalid</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `ngSwitchCase` only seems to use loose equality `==` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_switch.ts

Answer (score 0):

ngSwitch same as switch case in programing. You have to give fixed option value.

If you want to make the section as dynamic, use *ngIf instead of ngSwitch.

Answer (score 0):

How can you make Angular Code Snippets? Would love to test this, but imho something like this should work:

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="'static_string'">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="{{ (grade >= 75 && grade <= 80) ? 'static_string' : '' }}">Average</div>
    <div *ngSwitchDefault>Invalid</div>
</div>
```

and if this works, then this should work too:

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="'true'">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="{{ grade >= 75 && grade <= 80 }}">Average</div>
    <div *ngSwitchDefault>Invalid</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ngSwitch` uses a specific value in the condition.
Try to use `*ngIf` for each condition or make a new `Pipe` to transform `grade` to a constant value like

```
type Grade = 'Average' | 'Master' | 'Invalid';

@Pipe({name: 'gradeClass'})
export class GradeTransformer implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number): Grade {
    switch (true) {
      case (value >= 75 && value <= 80): {
        return 'Average';
      }
      case (value > 80): {
        return 'Master';
      }
      default: {
        return 'Invalid';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and in your component. just:

```
{{ grade | gradeClass }}
```